# is upload image to firebase storage needs permission?how?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am about to publish my new android java app,
I upload image profile to firebase storage,
Its working,
Without any permissions requests,
I am afraid that my app may not be accepted in app store because of no asking for permission,
So the question is:
is upload image to firebase storage needs permission and how?

Answer (score 0):

If you performed a normal integration of the Cloud Storage SDK for Firebase, then you don't need to do anything special.  Your app will have all the required permissions by default.

Comment: do you mean by "normal integration of the Cloud Storage SDK for Firebase" this line?    
                      >>implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'

Comment: Yes, if you followed the instructions in the documentation.  That's all you have to do.  Adding the library will automatically merge in the required permissions into your app.

Answer (score 0):

After added os version M.  You need ask Run time permission for access storage.

Comment: my device version is P and my emulator is Q, and no error permission appears to me, but to To be careful i think that i should ask for permission,can you give me simple code for ask for the suitable permission

Comment: service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

Comment: i am working in java android project,where i can place this code?

Comment: Put it in firebase console.. Inside storage security